# What is the most efficient way to store temporary data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My problem is like,

I would like to store some data after a user logs in.  Need to keep it until the user logs out. Many solutions came into discussion like xml file, session, cookies....

Any better way to accomplish this?

Comment: You can go with Session.

Comment: whats wrong with all the methods you mentioned?

Comment: @freebird Is that good to stack multiple session values in a project?

Comment: @TaylorGibb cookies...fails if the user is doesn't support cookies. Files fails is number of user increases

Comment: You can use normal ASP.Net session state and provide your custom way of getting session id. I.e. instead of using default one from cookies you can create custom one based on user's identity which somehow (assuming magic, since no cookies/no Url modification means no auth for GET reuests from browser) comes with each request... Check out [SessionIdManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionidmanager(v=vs.100).aspx) for it.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP Sessions is the way to go.

Storing data on the local file system isn't scalable. As you add more webservers, it's going to be harder to ensure your clients hit the same server over and over again. ASP and IIS has figured this problem out with sessions.

Sessions are typically implemented ontop of cookies, and for security reasons, you should probably stick with Session over manually rolling your own cookies.

Comment: +1 to all "use Session" also it clearly specified in question that OP considers it inferior :). Storing data on local system could be scalable and interesting to implement - i.e. sticky connections + lazy replication + some sort of voting algorithms to decide what copy is latest...

Comment: Storing data on the local file system could be made scalable, but its not going to work the first time, and is way more trouble than it's worth. Why reinvent the wheel if you dont have to? When companies like google, and Facebook, and twitter, that sever 1000k requests per second, it makes sense to think outside the box. By and large, the standard way of doing things works, and there isn't a reason to deviate if you dont tneed to.

Comment: Yes, completely agree if question is for practical applications (I'd guess one would need to think about tuning or changing state storage from default ASP.Net SQL state much earlier that 1M requests per second... 1-10K would be probably more realistic... still one would need well above 1M+ users to hit such numbers). If question was asked from more entertainment point of view - implementing session state is not too hard and not that interesting... while some other approach could be.

Answer (score 1):

One of  good way is to make use of Session Variable if you want to remove data once user get logged out of system. i.e if you want to store data from user login to logout.

[**ASP.NET session state enables you to store and retrieve values for a user as the user navigates ASP.NET pages in a Web application.**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

you can also check : [**Exploring Session in ASP.NET**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32545/Exploring-Session-in-ASP-Net)

Comment: Is there any other way around?

Comment: @Anjana - this is safe way and session is made up for storing user session data...so its goodd that you use session ...there are no of different way also but i think is the good way

Answer (score 1):

Actually its the main idea of Sessionvariables, cookies are as good depending on which information would you like to keep, for more security sessions are better.

Comment: Is there any other way around?

Comment: You can use text files or any other type of file, you can keep in memory too, but these options arent as safe and performant as sessionvariables

Comment: Can Caching be used as a solution for this?

Comment: Never done it, but i would be interrested to know how the performance would be if you have a big amout of data. found this here take alook: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558270.aspx

Comment: Im reading a abit about the Cache class, it sounds no bad idea at al, you can set the amount of memory beeign sued to chache before ASP.NET starts removing items from the cache. and you can access items by key which may be user_ids in you app, and its thread safe

Comment: But notice the Cache is on Application level, and all users are in the same application. If you need a per-user Cache you could use the Sessionvariables.

Answer (score 0):

In light of my experience and this link [Data pasing methods](http://steveorr.net/articles/PassData.aspx) My final advice would be :

**COOKIES** for:

- ENCRYPT[userId's]
- ENCRYPT[productId]
- ENCRYPT[xyzIds..]
- ENCRYPT[etc..]

**DATABASE** for:

- datasets BY COOKIE ID
- datatables BY COOKIE ID
- all other large chunks BY COOKIE ID

My advise also depends on the below statistics and this link details [Data pasing methods](http://steveorr.net/articles/PassData.aspx) :

[image]